# Como usar sleep pra da um efeito de carregamento interface gráfica tkinter

Tags: python-3.x, tkinter, time

Estou querendo usar o *sleep* do módulo *time* pra da um efeito de carregamento/espera na verificação de uma condição. Sem usar funções da *tkinter*, o efeito funciona perfeitamente, porém, quando tento fazer o mesmo com a *Label* da *tkinter*, isso já não funciona. Alguém saberia me dizer o por quê?
segue um código exemplo abaixo:

```
from tkinter import *
from time import sleep

# Janela qualquer
janela = Tk()

# Variáveis com valores hipotéticos
a = 12
b = 15

lb_relacao_vh = Label(janela, font=("Century Gothic", 10, "bold"), bd=5,
                    text="Verificando a relação vão/altura.", anchor="w")
lb_relacao_vh.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=W)
sleep(1)
lb_relacao_vh['text'] = "Verificando a relação vão/altura.."
sleep(1)
lb_relacao_vh['text'] = "Verificando a relação vão/altura..."

if a > b:
   lb_relacao_vh['fg'] = 'red'
   lb_relacao_vh['text'] = 'Verificando a relação vão/altura...ERRO!'
else:
   lb_relacao_vh['fg'] = 'green'
   lb_relacao_vh['text'] = 'Verificando a relação vão/altura...OK!'


janela.mainloop()
```

Comment: O `sleep()` gera um bloqueio na execução do código, para que isso não ocorra você deve executar o `sleep()` de forma assíncrona.
No Python algumas opções são o `multiprocessing`, `threading` ou `asyncio`.
Tive um problema parecido quando precisei gerar um gráfico ([Exemplo](https://natorsc.github.io/Tkinter/exemplos/plotar_grafico/)) que ficava atualizando sozinho.

Comment: Olá @RenatoCruz não entendi muito bem como posso aplicar isso no meu exemplo (estou aprendendo por conta própria e por isso não entendo algumas coisas)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basicamente o interpretador Python está lendo **linha por linha** do seu código, quando ele chega na linha do `sleep()` ele fica parado até que o tempo que foi passado acabe (repare que a janela não abre).

Depois que o tempo do sleep() acaba ele:

- Configura o widget.
- Faz a verificação do `if`.
- Entra no `mainloop()` agora a janela é criada e exibida, contudo o widget já está pronto.

Para evitar isso a interface deve ser criada ao mesmo tempo que fazemos o `sleep()`, a configuração e a verificação (`if`), por isso o código deve ser assíncrono (**neste caso**).

Me baseando no seu código e sem fazer grandes alterações ou mudança do paradigma, cheguei a este código:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""Código assíncrono (threading)"""

import threading
import tkinter as tk
from time import sleep

# Janela qualquer (main window)
janela = tk.Tk()

# Variáveis com valores hipotéticos
a = 12
b = 15

# Criando o widget.
lb_relacao_vh = tk.Label(janela, font=("Century Gothic", 10, "bold"), bd=5,
                         text="Verificando a relação vão/altura.", anchor=tk.W)
# Posicionando o widget na janela.
lb_relacao_vh.grid(row=0, column=0, sticky=tk.W)


# Método que será executado de forma assíncrona.
def verificar_altura():
    lb_relacao_vh['text'] = "Verificando a relação vão/altura."
    sleep(1)
    lb_relacao_vh['text'] = "Verificando a relação vão/altura.."
    sleep(1)
    lb_relacao_vh['text'] = "Verificando a relação vão/altura..."
    sleep(1)

    if a > b:
        lb_relacao_vh['fg'] = 'red'
        lb_relacao_vh['text'] = 'Verificando a relação vão/altura...ERRO!'
    else:
        lb_relacao_vh['fg'] = 'green'
        lb_relacao_vh['text'] = 'Verificando a relação vão/altura...OK!'


# Executando o método em um thead do processador diferente daquele onde está o loop da janela.
threading.Thread(target=verificar_altura, daemon=True).start()

# Loop que fica repetindo a janela (FPS).
janela.mainloop()
```

Se não for essa a ideia vai comentando para podermos refinar o código ou até mesmo localizar outras possibilidades.

Comment: eu testei o código que você sugeriu e realmente deu certo, porém, gostaria de aproveitar oportunidade para tirar mais uma dúvida: em códigos de mais de uma estrutura condicionante em que a condição utiliza dados da anterior e entre a execução destas, gostaria de implementar o tempo de espera. No estilo a seguir: Verificação1... Ok; Verificação2...Ok e assim por diante.